# Changing viewmodel properties without making the page flash

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I was hoping that I could get some ideas on this:

Im attempting to create a "Show more results" feature on the website that Im working on.  Currently, there is a list of ten items that are currently being shown using razor syntax.

```
@foreach (Movie m in Model.MovieList)
{
   <li>
      @Html.RouteLink("Details", "Details", new { detailsId = m.Id }, new { @class = "hidden double-click-href" })
      <h1>
         @(m.CurrentIdentifier): @m.MovieTitle
         <span class="right">@m.Movie.Description</span>
       </h1>
         <div class="fields">
            <span class="label">Release Date</span>
            <span class="value">@m.CreatedOn.ToShortDateString()</span>
            <span class="label">Genre</span>
            <span class="value">@m.Genre.Name</span>
         </div>
   </li>
}
```

There is a link "Show More Results" that, when clicked, will append the next 10 cases to the list with a query.  The only way I could think to do it was to create an ajax call using JQuery that would call an action, return the JSON results with the information I needed, and fill in a string that is the "template" (duplicate) of the HTML above using a JavaScript method.

The issue is that I do not like the fact that HTML is basically being duplicated and if I attempt to fill in the MovieList property during the call to the action (I need to make it ajax or something similar so that there is no "flashing") it will not be picked up until the page refreshes.

Is there a good way to set the MovieList property so that I do not have to duplicate the HTML and still make the ajax call (not have the page post back)?

**Edit:**

I attempted the suggestion of @Jamie Dixon and, while I see the request and I can see the proper HTML is being returned, it is not updating the page (the page stays exactly the same as before I clicked the link).  Here is the javascript:

```
 function GetMovieList() {
    var url = location.pathname + '/Filter';
    var size = $('#my-movie-list > li').size();

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      data: { fromNumber: size }, //the number of rows already displayed
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      success: function (data) {
      SetShowMoreResultsFeatures(); //checks to see if the 'Show More Results' link should be disabled and some other stuff.
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is the controller method:

```
[Route("/Filter")]
public ActionResult GetFilteredMovies(int fromNumber)
{
  ViewData.Model = new DashboardIndexViewModel
  {
    CurrentUser = CurrentUser.User,
    MyCalendar = new CalendarListView(CurrentUser.User),
    CaseCount = movieQuery.Execute(CurrentUser.User.Id).Count(),
    Movies= GetMovies(fromNumber)
  };


  return View("_MovieItem", ViewData.Model);
}
```

and here is the Partial View "_MovieItem":

```
@model Matrix.Investigator.Website.ViewModels.Dashboard.DashboardIndexViewModel

@foreach (Movie m in Model.MovieList)
{
   <li>
      @Html.RouteLink("Details", "Details", new { detailsId = m.Id }, new { @class = "hidden double-click-href" })
      <h1>
         @(m.CurrentIdentifier): @m.MovieTitle
         <span class="right">@m.Movie.Description</span>
       </h1>
         <div class="fields">
            <span class="label">Release Date</span>
            <span class="value">@m.CreatedOn.ToShortDateString()</span>
            <span class="label">Genre</span>
            <span class="value">@m.Genre.Name</span>
         </div>
   </li>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your HTML in a partial view that iterates over a collection to output its HTML.

When you make your ajax call to your controller method, have the controller return the *same* partial view and pass it your new collection.

You can then simply drop your returned HTML data into the relevant part of your page and there's no duplication.

Comment: I updated everything and, while I can see the correct html being created and returned from the request, it is NOT updating the pages so I continue to see the first 10 movies instead of the 20 I should see after I click the link.  What am i doing wrong?  To let you know, "Index" is the name of the view that the partial view is being  called from when the page initially loads.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: What is in your data variable when the success handler fires?

Comment: Your method SetShowMoreResultsFeatures(), how is this obtaining the data from your ajax call? What happens inside this function? I'm guessing you need to pass the data to it?

Comment: SetShowMoreResultsFeatures() simply sets the "Showing n of m" text and either disables or enables the link for "Show more results" link depending on whether or not the user has hit the max number of rows it can show them.  That is all.  The data variable is something that I forgot to remove when I added the changes.  It should now be returning the view, actually.

Comment: The data returned in your ajax request is important. That's the bit that contains the results you want to append to your list, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the way that I had it before I created the partial view.  Before I changed it based on  your answer Id have the controller simply return an object array that had all the information in it needed to fill in the string that was a duplicate of the loop that rendered them.  Then I used JQuery to append them to the HTML.  Now the code looks like the above (the edit portion).  Im sure I misunderstood.  Should I simply take the 'data' and append it to the html like before?

Comment: HA! I just tried it that way and it worked.  How foolish of me!  Thanks so much.  This is a great solution!